# why cannot I see my modal when I increased number?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Can you please show me why my Modal is not show up when I increased number?
Counting is working but Modal is not working.
I want to show Modal when I increase number. Thank you

```
function App() {
  const [count, setCoutn] = useState(0)
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false)


 const increase = () => {
  setCoutn(count + 1)
  setShowModal(true)
 }

  return (
    <>
     
      { showModal && < Modal /> }
      <p className="text-center mt-5 mt-5 fs-5 count">{count}</p>
      <div className="btn-box">

        <button className="btn btn-outline-primary" onClick={()=>increase()}>increase</button>

      </div>
    </>
  );
}


const Modal = () => {
  return (
     <div>
       <p className='modal'>Modal</p>   
     </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Check your demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-khorana-sixouv?file=/src/App.js:466-484)

instead of :

```
onClick={()=>increase()}
```

But I recommend using:

```
onClick={increase}
```

Because it will call the function increase directly when clicking the button.

Comment: thank you ,but  this way is not working for me onClick={increase}

Comment: if I set up const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(true)  I cannot see Modal

Comment: I used your code to create a sandbox, it actually worked. I am confused.

Answer (score 0):

```
 **You cant see modal,because showModal is false default!**
    

function App() {
      const [count, setCoutn] = useState(0)
      const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false)
    
    
     const increase = () => {
      setCoutn(count + 1)
      setShowModal(true)
     }
      if(showModal) {
      return (
        <>
          <p className="text-center mt-5 mt-5 fs-5 count">{count}</p>
          <div className="btn-box">
    
            <button className="btn btn-outline-primary" onClick={()=>increase()}>increase</button>
    
          </div>
        </>
      );
    }else{
        return (
         <div>
           <p className='modal'>Modal</p>   
         </div>
      )
    }
    }
```

Comment: but now you also cant see modal because your showmodal is false.if you want to see modal first than change showModal true and when click button setShowModal to false!